# Is zero an element of the empty set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question about the empty set.

> Is $0$ (zero) an element of $\varnothing$? And what is the cardinality of {0}?

Comment: The empty set has **no elements**.

Comment: Perhaps you should repeat in high voice the definition of the "empty set" ...

Comment: The cardinality of $\{0\}$ is $1$.

Comment: Funny enough, some set theorists may say that $\{0\}$ actually *is* $1$ (and that $0=\emptyset$).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Most probably those set theorists would *also* give a set up of assumptions, axioms, etc. in which that would make some sense....or they are high, of course. :)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes, but even so, $0 \not \in 0 = \emptyset$ and $0 \in 1 = \{0\} \ne \emptyset$ and $1=|1| = |\{0\}|$ so ... no problem.  Anyway.  The empty set has NO elements.  0, if it is in a set, is an element.  So $0 \not \in \emptyset$.

Comment: ∅ = 0 means the cardinality?

Comment: @fleablood I know and I've never said otherwise.

Comment: G. sassatelli.  I wasn't disagreeing.  Just clarifying potential confusion.

Comment: @HazemAlabiad In that context, it *also* means the cardinality, but it is primarily meant as an identity of sets. When you identify $\Bbb N$ with the first limit ordinal, and specifically $0$ with $\emptyset$ and $n+1$ with $n\cup\{n\}$, you get a whole bunch of identifications.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Well, thanks ... got it ...  :)

Comment: @HazemAlabiad  No.    That cardinality is written inside "bars".  $|\emptyset| = 0$.  The empty set is a set with no elements.  If anyone says $\emptyset = 0$, they are somewhat advance set theoreticians and they are refering to they construction of the natural numbers via set theory.  In such studies *EVERYTHING* including numbers, are defined and constructed by sets. For now, $\emptyset \ne 0$ as 0 is a number; not a set.  *Later* you will learn how numbers *are* sets, but lets not worry about that yet.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah ... I see, because it's an introduction course ... Ok, I'll consider it as you mention right now ... thanks ...

Comment: Bottom line.  The empty set is the set that does not have *any* elements.  So $x \in \emptyset$ is NEVER true and $0 \in \emptyset$ is NOT true.  {0} is a set with one element and $0 \in {0}$.  So ${0} \ne \emptyset$.  Not at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The empty set is *empty*.  It doesn't contain anything.  Nothing and zero are not the same thing.

Comment: Well, nothing is "nothing".

Comment: @fleablood  Look at it this way:  The set of all integers less than 1 and greater than -1 is $\{0\}$.  The set of all integers greater than 1 and less than 2 is $\emptyset$.  The two are not the same thing.

Comment: Of course not.  I was pointing that nothing is "nothing".  Nothing and zero are not the same that but nothing and "nothing" are not the same thing either.

Comment: @fleablood OK, I think I hear you.

Comment: Isn’t zero supposed to represent nothing, tho?

Answer (score 9):

You have two boxes separate from each other. One box contains nothing. The other box has a piece of paper with the number zero on it. The first box represents $\{ \} = \emptyset$ while the second represents $\{ 0 \}$. Two different things. The first has no objects, the second has only one.